# Как проверить, есть ли записи в запросе?

Tags: php

При запросе в бд нужно понять, содержит ли он записи. Как мне это проверить?

```
class TestUser{
    public $login;

    public $password;

    private $link;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "testdb");
    }

    public function chek(){
        $query ="SELECT login FROM users WHERE login=?";
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $this->login);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ($result) { ... }`

Comment: Не работает. Всегда активируется if, даже если в запросе не будет записей

Comment: попробуйте `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` вместо `$stmt->get_result();` и проверить есть там в массиве что-то

Comment: `$result->num_rows;` и посмотрите уже документацию на mysqli. Возможно, перед этим нужно будет вызвать `$stmt->store_result();`

Comment: У меня получилось ` if ($result->num_rows == 1){...}`